# ORA-00904: "E_MAIL": invalid identifier

Tags: c++, oracle, model-view-controller, proc

I am using MVC architecture.I am trying to update a record in a table taking customer id as input.
all the data is taken as input in my viewcustomer.cpp class whose method is returning an object of type customer which is passed to a function in modelcustomer.pc via controlcustomer.cpp(controller)
Following is a function of my modelcustomer.pc

```
void modelcustomer::dbUpdateCustomerDetail(customer &c)
{

id=c.getId();
ph=c.getId();
string memberFName=c.getFname();
string memberLName=c.getLname();
string memberStreet=c.getStreet();
string memberCity=c.getCity();
string memberState=c.getState();
string memberEmail=c.getEmail();
fn=new char[memberFName.length()+1];
ln=new char[memberLName.length()+1];
street=new char[memberStreet.length()+1];
city=new char[memberCity.length()+1];
state=new char[memberState.length()+1];
e_mail=new char[memberEmail.length()+1];
strcpy(fn,memberFName.c_str());
strcpy(ln,memberLName.c_str());
strcpy(street,memberStreet.c_str());
strcpy(city,memberCity.c_str());
strcpy(state,memberState.c_str());
strcpy(e_mail,memberEmail.c_str());
if(dbConnect())
{
EXEC SQL UPDATE CUSTOMER_1030082 SET CID=:id,FNAME=:fn,LNAME=:ln,PHONE=:ph,STREET=:street,STATE=:state,CITY=:city,EMAIL=e_mail;
if(sqlca.sqlcode<0)
{
cout<<"error in execution"<<sqlca.sqlcode<<sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrmc;
}
EXEC SQL COMMIT WORK RELEASE;
}
}
```

when i'm running it a menu is displayed with some options ,i select the update option then it asks me for new details and after that  i'm getting following output:

```
connected to Oracle!
error in execution-904ORA-00904: "E_MAIL": invalid identifier
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e_mail` is not a parameter, you forgot `:`:

```
EXEC SQL … EMAIL=:e_mail;
                 ↑
```